# Wake from suspend issue on Alder Lake-P

Tags: suspend, intel-graphics, 22.04, intel

I have a new ThinkPad P14s Gen 3 laptop, similar to a T14 G3.

Relevant Specs:

- Intel i7-1280P
- 3840 x 2400 IPS Touchscreen
- NVIDIA Quadro T550

Loving the machine so far on 22.04, except it will not wake from suspend. It appears to go to sleep, the indicator light begins breathing like a normal sleeping ThinkPad, although the fan still remains on. Upon waking it up the screen stays black (backlight on). After some time it will flash the login screen before blacking out again.

It is using the S2 idle sleep state. I can change it to S3 in the BIOS, but then it breaks sleep in Windows and doesn't solve the problem in Linux anyways. I have tried multiple kernel versions including the default 5.15.x-generic Ubuntu kernel, 5.18.15, and 5.19.0. Same issues in Pop_OS! as well.

I was able to run `sudo rmmod intel_lpss_pci`, which seemed to 'fix' the issue, but naturally that makes my keyboard and trackpad nonfunctional. Due to this and me temporarily disabling the GPU I'm pretty sure it's an intel-based possibly display-related issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Yeah same here. From what I gather from another forum (linked below) about a T16, a fix will be released in the next bios update. https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Other-Linux-Discussions/Thinkpad-T16-can-t-resume-from-suspend/m-p/5160642?page=1

Comment: Got roughly the same issue with a T14 gen 3
12th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1265U × 12
Mesa Intel® Graphics (ADL GT2)
On 22.04.1
Cant wake from suspend. 
Screen backlight is on when opening lid and login screen flashes on sometimes but it doesnt seem to register input.